# Why the leetcode runtime result different from my local result?

Tags: c++, algorithm

This question is about [leetcode 403. Frog Jump](https://leetcode.com/problems/frog-jump/?tab=Description)

The leetcode runtime result is different from my local result. I used dynamic programming and C++ to solve the problem. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

void print(vector<vector<bool>>& matrix) {
    for(auto row: matrix) {
        for(auto item: row) {
            cout << item << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void eval(vector<int>& nums, map<int, int>& index, vector<vector<bool>>& dp, int i, int j) {
    auto i1 = index.find(nums[i] - (j - 1));
    if(i1 != index.end())
        dp[i][j] = (dp[i][j] || dp[i1->second][j - 1]);
    auto i2 = index.find(nums[i] - j);
    if(i2 != index.end())
        dp[i][j] = (dp[i][j] || dp[i2->second][j]);
    auto i3 = index.find(nums[i] - (j + 1));
    if(i3 != index.end())
        dp[i][j] = (dp[i][j] || dp[i3->second][j + 1]);
}

bool canCross(vector<int>& stones) {
    int n = stones.size();
    map<int, int> index;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        index[stones[i]] = i;
    vector<vector<bool>> dp(n, vector<bool>(n, false));
    dp[0][1] = true;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
            eval(stones, index, dp, i, j);
        }
    }
    print(dp);
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if(dp[n - 1][i])
            return true;
    return false;
}

int main() {
    int val;
    vector<int> nums;
    while(cin >> val)
        nums.push_back(val);
    int res = canCross(nums);
    cout << res << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Testcase: "[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,12]"

When I run my code locally, it is right, and the output:

```
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0
```

I used c++11, and I compiled my source code with the command:

> g++ -std=c++11 -o test 403.cpp

The gcc compiler version information is:

> 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)

I ran my code many times locally, and the result is always the above.

But when I submit my solution to leetcode oj. It told me "Wrong answer":

```
Input:
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,12]
Output:
true
Expected:
false
Stdout:
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Apparently, something went wrong. Maybe my solution is not a correct solution for this problem, but why is the leetcode runtime result different from my local result? I am not an experienced coder and I don't have a clear understanding of the Leetcode OJ mechanism. I google this and read the Leetcode FAQ, and haven't found an answer.

If someone who is knowledgeable regarding my question could interpret what happened with my code, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I ran your code and got the same result as yours.

Comment: The local result different from the leetcode runtime result? It is so ridiculous, I don't know this is about C++ Language attribute or my code errors, even the Leetcode OJ bug.

Comment: Can you add some debug output? good old-fashioned `printf`'s and see what leetcode runtime does.

Comment: I don't know output what. And I can't output too much because that may cause Leetcode output overlimit error.

Comment: There is a bug in their system. On their website, instead of submitting the program, click on "Custom Testcase" and put in the input `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,12]` It gives correct answer, your answer: `false` and expected: `false`  . But if you submit the same code, it starts going through the test-case and it gives error on this input.

Comment: Thanks. I try it as you say. My code pass this testcase. I will reply this bug to Leetcode.

Comment: @DandissValjean did you report the bug? Got any response?